# 'Missing operator' in batch for statement

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am getting 3 `Missing operator.` lines as output from the following batch script

```
SET w3wp2ID=0
SET w3wp1ID=0
SET w3wpID=0
SET ValuesAreSet=FALSE

for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims=," %%A in ('typeperf -sc 1 -y "\Process(w3wp*)\ID Process" ^| find /V "\\" ^| find /V "please wait..."') do (
    if "%ValuesAreSet%"=="FALSE" (
        SET /A w3wp2ID=%%~A+0
        SET /A w3wp1ID=%%~B+0
        SET /A w3wpID=%%~C+0
    )
    SET ValuesAreSet=TRUE
)
```

At first I thought the output was coming from the 3 `Set` statements in the forloop, but upon investigation I no longer think this is the issue. Leading me to believe it has something to do with the `for` statement itself, but I cannot figure out what exactly is wrong.

I need to suppress these warnings since the output of this script will be logged.

Any help is appreciated, thanks, T.

EDIT: I should add that the 3 variables are getting the correct values set.

Comment: Have you tried using `+=` rather than just `+`?

Comment: Just tried, no difference

Comment: If it's working but just showing an error, you could suppress them by putting  `>nul 2>&1` at the end of the sets (which must be the source of the errors?)

Comment: What is the output of `typeperf -sc 1 -y "\Process(w3wp*)\ID Process" | find /V "\\" | find /V "please wait..."` ? I'd insert an echo %%A %%B %%C in front of the if.

Comment: @LotPings when I inserted those echos the output was as follows `"9652.000000"`
`"12620.000000"`
`"5316.000000"`
`Missing operator.`
`Missing operator.`
`Missing operator.`

Comment: @BaliC your suggestion works, I no longer see the messages, but I wonder why I see them at all?

Comment: Set /A only handles integers, it doesn't like the dots in `9652.000000` etc.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Though the reason for that Set /A is to change that to an int, is there another way to do that other then using Set?

Comment: It looks like set is ok, but it just rounds up the number

Comment: Was the ValuesAreSet variable neccessary? If it really is, you should probably add `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and change the `%` to `!` so the changed value is directly updated (I think).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the values before the decimal point just use the `%~nI` expansion method which would treat the numbers after the decimal point as an extension thus removing them. *(technically rounding it down)*.

```bat
SET "ValuesAreSet=FALSE"

For /F "Tokens=2-4 Delims=," %%A In (
    'typeperf -sc 1 -y "\Process(w3wp*)\ID Process" ^| find /V "\\" ^| find /V "please wait..."'
) Do If "%ValuesAreSet%"=="FALSE" (SET "w3wp2ID=%%~nA"
    SET "w3wp1ID=%%~nB"
    SET "w3wpID=%%~nC"
    SET "ValuesAreSet=TRUE"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if suppressing the error messages is ok for you then stay with it,
parsing the values to split at the dot is IMO overkill, but nevertheless:

```
SET w3wp2ID=0
SET w3wp1ID=0
SET w3wpID=0
SET ValuesAreSet=FALSE

for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims=," %%A in ('typeperf -sc 1 -y "\Process(w3wp*)\ID Process" ^| find /V "\\" ^| find /V "please wait..."') do (
    if "%ValuesAreSet%"=="FALSE" (
        for /f "delims=." %%x in ("%%~A") do SET /A w3wp2ID+=%%x
        for /f "delims=." %%x in ("%%~B") do SET /A w3wp1ID+=%%x
        for /f "delims=." %%x in ("%%~C") do SET /A w3wpID+=%%x
    )
    SET ValuesAreSet=TRUE
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Although for this specific case the [method explained by Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43260383) is probably the best solution for the problem at hand, I still want to contribute another approach: letting the `set /A` command do the variable expansion, because this does not rise errors if non-numeric values are stored; instead, everything up to the first non-numeric character is converted to a signed 32-bit integer, omitting leading white-spaces, regarding signs and coercing it to the 32-bit bounds. For example:

```cmd
set "VAR=  -1.5 mV" & rem // (the first non-numeric char. is `.`, so the integer is `-1`)
set /A "VAR=VAR"    & rem // (`VAR` is read by `set /A`, because no `%%` are surrounded)
echo %VAR% (-1 expected, no error message arises)

set /A "VAR=%VAR%"  & rem /* (`VAR` becomes set to `-1` here, but an error message appears,
                      rem     because `set /A` actually receives the string `  -1.5 mV`) */
echo %VAR% (-1 expected, an error message arises)
```

Here this functionality is implemented into your code; the values are first stored unaltered with a standard `set` command, then converted to integers by a `set /A` command (note that `VAR=VAR` has been replaced by `VAR+=0`, just not to have to state each variable name twice per statement):

```cmd
set "ValuesAreSet="
for /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=," %%A in ('
    typeperf -sc 1 -y "\Process(w3wp*)\ID Process" ^
        ^| find /V "\\" ^| find /V "please wait..."
') do if not defined ValuesAreSet (
    set "w3wp2ID=%%~A" & set /A "w3wp2ID+=0"
    set "w3wp1ID=%%~B" & set /A "w3wp1ID+=0"
    set "w3wpID=%%~C" & set /A "w3wpID+=0"
    set "ValuesAreSet=#"
)
```

In addition, I changed the flag-style variable `ValuesAreSet` to indicate the `FALSE` state by being empty and the `TRUE` state by being non-empty, so `if defined ValuesAreSet` can be used.